# Is log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender class removed since the 1.2.11 release?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

In the **log4net** version **1.2.11** there was the **log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender** class.
My following log4net configuration works great with the 1.2.11 version of the log4net:

```xml
  <appender name="AsyncAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
  </appender>
```

After upgrading to the **1.2.12** or to the currently latest **1.2.13** version, I'm getting following exception when my app starts:

```xml
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in log4net.dll    
Additional information: Could not load type [log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies
```

I've taken a look into the **log4net 1.2.11** assembly and found the log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender type, but there is no such type in the **1.2.12** and **1.2.13** version assemblies anywhere.
I've googled and researched at the log4net sources repository, but I can't find the answer **what's happened with the log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender** class in the latest versions of the log4net.

Could anybody answer that question please?

Comment: Was it ever part of the standard dll? I have 1.2.11 and I can't find a reference in the shipped dll and in the source code it is located in the folder log4net-1.2.11\examples\net\2.0\Appenders\SampleAppendersApp\cs\src\Appender and it appears to be in the same place for both 1.2.12 and 1.2.13.

Comment: Thank You, @sgmoore!  I've rechecked my log4net 1.2.11 assembly and found out that it differs from the standard DLL available at:  http://archive.apache.org/dist/logging/log4net/binaries/log4net-1.2.11-bin-newkey.zip. I guess now there is some non-standard log4net DLL in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various `AsyncAppender` classes are now part of the `Log4Net.Async` assembly, as developed by Chris Haines.

```
<appender name="AsyncRollingFileAppender" type="Log4Net.Async.AsyncRollingFileAppender,Log4Net.Async" >
  //.....
</appender>
```

These are available as a NuGet package (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Log4Net.Async/) and the source is available on GitHub at https://github.com/cjbhaines/Log4Net.Async.

Answer (score 1):

**log4net.Appender.AsyncAppender** class isn't a part of the standard **log4net** DLL.
I have some non-standard log4net DLL in my project.

**If You're looking for an implementation of an async appender for log4net**, try it out from the log4net example available here (the link provided by @sgmoore):
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/examples/net/2.0/Appenders/SampleAppendersApp/cs/src/Appender/AsyncAppender.cs?revision=1158529&view=markup&sortby=file&pathrev=1181618